# Double-precision Random number array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, precision

got some homework to produce a program that loads and displays double-precision random numbers with an array size of 20.
i know its messy but not to good at this

```
#include <iostream> //required for cin, cout, endl
#include <cstdlib> //required for setw(), setfill()
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


void printArray(int arr[]); 
void fillRandArray(int arr[]);
void fillDecimalArray(double dArr[]); 
void printDecimalArray (double dArr[]);

int main()
{

    int random[21];
    double decimal[21]; 
    rand();

    fillRandArray(random); 
    fillDecimalArray(decimal);
    printArray(random); 
    printDecimalArray(decimal);


    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void fillRandArray(int arr[]) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }

}//end load of rand array

void fillDecimalArray(double dArr[ ])
{
    for (double i = 1; i <21; i++)
    {
        dArr[i] = static_cast<double>(rand()%100)/10;
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[]) 
{
    cout <<  "          5x4 Array" <<endl;
    cout <<endl;

    int cols = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << setfill(' '); 
        cout << arr[i];
        if(i%cols == 0)
            cout << endl;
    }//end print array

}//end of printArray()

void printDecimalArray (double dArr[])
{
    int cols = 4;

    for (double i = 1; i <21; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << setfill(' '); 
        int precision = 2;
        cout << dArr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

needs to be displayed in 4x5 table 
errors are ' invalid types 'double*[double]' for array subscript '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (double i = 1; i <21; i++)
{
    dArr[i] = static_cast<double>(rand()%100)/10;
```

You cannot access into an array with a double (i.e. `dArr[i]` is invalid because i isn't an integer type - it's a double precision floating point value), must be an integral type.  Just make i an int and you'll be good.

That said, your loops from 1-20 instead of 0-19 will work (since you make your arrays 1 element too big), but you shouldn't do it.   Get used to writing

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
```

and then just allocate the array of the correct size (in your example here, 20 instead of 21)

Comment: taken your advice and it now compiles which is great, but the decimal array has a range of .1-1.0 intead of 1.00-100.00
any ideas?

Comment: scratch that, figured it out, but my double precision isn't working

Comment: That's weird.  I'd expect `dArr[i] = static_cast<double>(rand()%100)/10;` to give values 0 - 9.9   -- the values of your double will be the double representation of the integers from 0 - 99 and then you divide that by 10 - so 0-9.9.   What people often do is cast rand() to double, divide that by RAND_MAX then multiply that result (make sure you do it in the right order or you get overflow) by the desired range maximum.   So you get a double equally distributed over the range 0-1 and then multiply that by 100 or whatever the max should be.

Comment: `dArr[i] = rand()%100 + static_cast<double>(rand()%100)/100;`

I'm going somewhere wrong here, I need the value to be double precision and between 1.00-100.00

Comment: that is going to give you a very strange distribution -- and it's not random.  It's the whole "roll two dice and add them" distribution, except one die has values 100x bigger than the other.

Comment: my teacher has added hints next to the question and its confusing me
The question is as follows "Loads array of double-precision(decimal)values with random numbers in the range 1.00 – 100.00. To generate a floating point random number use rand()%100 for a whole part, plus static_cast<double>(rand()%100)/100 as a decimal part"

Comment: Best of luck - I have to go to sleep

Answer (score 4):

C++11 onwards, you can use [std::uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

```
#include <random>
...
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
const double min_v = 1.0, max_v = 100.0;
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(min_v, max_v);
for (int n = 0; n < 20; ++n) {
//           ^    ^ ^^
    dArr[n] = dis(gen);
}
```

**[Link to example](http://ideone.com/XXQTX5)**

If you use loop in range (1-20), use `cout << arr[i-1];` or use loop in range (0-19) and change condition to `if((i + 1) % cols == 0) ...`

---

If you must use `rand()` to generate these numbers, you can use:

```
dArr[n] = 1 + (rand() % 99) + static_cast<double>(rand() % 101) / 100.0;
// Expression                         Range
// [1] rand() % 99                    0 - 98
// [2] 1 + (rand() % 99)              1 - 99
// [3] rand() % 101                   0 - 100
// [4] (rand() % 101) / 100.0         0.00 - 1.00
// [5] [2] + [4]                      1.00 - 100.0
```

But we warned that:

1. the distribution of random numbers generated using any such expressions is not uniform.
2. Always use `std::srand` with a variable (possibly `std::time(0)`) to get different output on multiple execution of same binary.